# How can i record Screen which can also captures screen audio as well as video and compatible for all kind of web browser?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a JavaScript project and I want to place a button that can record the screen and the audio coming from it. I implemented it through

```
mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia
```

This API is working perfectly for Chrome but in Firefox and some other browsers, screen audio is not coming. Is there any way to capture screen audio better than this which supports other browsers.

```
              async function recordScreen() {
                    return await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
                    preferCurrentTab:'True',
                    systemAudio: "include",
                    audio: 'True',

                    video: { mediaSource: "tab"}                             
                    });
                }
```

I am expecting a method to record the screen and its audio which work on the different browsers

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help you :

```
  const displayStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
    video: { mediaSource: "tab" },
    audio: { mandatory: {
      chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
      chromeMediaSourceId: 'screen:0',
      googEchoCancellation: true,
      googNoiseSuppression: true,
      googHighpassFilter: true,
      googTypingNoiseDetection: true,
      echoCancellation: true,
      noiseSuppression: true,
      highpassFilter: true,
      typingNoiseDetection: true,
    }}
  });
```

maybe adding these configs can do that for you

Comment: How this will work for Firefox? can you please elaborate?
Thanks!

Comment: this is the config to capture the audio generally. I thaught this might be helpful